# how get all keys who answer value conditions

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to use Redis and I would like obtain a result according to the values.

For example:

```
redis.hmset("user:"+id, "statut", 3);
redis.hmset("user:"+id, "statut", 2);
redis.hmset("user:"+id, "statut", 2);
```

I want have all keys which statut: 2

Is it possible with Redis and node JS ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Redis is not really designed for queries like this. You will have to scan through every entry and check the values:

```
redis.keys('user:*', function(err, results) {
  results.forEach(function(key) {
    redis.hget(key, 'statut', function(err, statut) {
      if (parseInt(statut) === 2) {
        console.log(key, statut);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

An alternative approach would be to store user IDs in a set depending on the field value you care about:

```
redis.sadd('statut:3', userId);
redis.sadd('statut:2', userId);
redis.sadd('statut:2', userId);
```

Then your query would look like:

```
redis.smembers('statut:2', function(err, userIds) {
  userIds.forEach(function(userId) {
    console.log(userId);
  });
});
```

Comment: Yess, thanks a lot ! But, datas will expire next 30 seconds if no refresh. And I can't set an expiration on a sadd isn't it?!

Comment: You cannot set a TTL on a particular value in a set, no.